# How to use long radicals to write nested roots?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, root

Well, I understand that expressing something like this is much easier to achieve using exponents that are equally valid and mathematically correct. But while it's the most obvious solution, I'm intrigued to know if there's a way to typeset in LaTeX something like what's shown in the following picture:

[image: Weird nested roots.]

My MNWE for solving the left side of the equality is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
\sqrt[-4]{\sqrt[\sqrt[-4]{\left(\dfrac{1}{4}\right)^{\sqrt[-4]{\dfrac{1}{4}}}}]{\dfrac{1}{4}} = 
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

and in fact, it doesn't compile because apparently I can't insert as an option all the code I have in there. A secondary problem is how to lengthen the initial trace of the root sign as in the image or if it already exists in LaTeX, I honestly ignore it and that's why I ask.

Regards

Comment: well getting it to compile is easy, you are only missing some braces. But I don't know a square symbol that stretches like this to the left.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for typesetting such nonsense?

Comment: @egreg Personally I'm interested to know if it is possible to typeset it in LaTeX, it's a question that I was asked a few hours ago and I couldn't solve it satisfactorily, outside of it I don't know the reasons to raise it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have nested optional arguments you need to enclose the inner argument in braces otherwise LaTeX becomes confused. That is, rather than writing

```
\sqrt[\sqrt[-4]{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}]{\frac14}
```

you need to write

```
\sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}}]{\frac14}
```

I think that you are over using `\dfrac` and `\left....\right`. If you use

```
\[
  \sqrt[-4]{\sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}}]{\frac14}}
  =\sqrt[-4]{\sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}^{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}}}]{4^{-1}}}
\]
```

then LaTeX will give you:

[image]

As Ulrike says in the comments, this fixes the compilation errors but the square root symbol does not underline the large "square root index". As a first attempt to fix this we could use `\underline`, together with [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) to improve the spacing. To this end define

```
\newcommand\Sqrt[2][]{\sqrt[\underline{#1}\hspace*{1mm}]{\cramped{#2}}}
```

to give a new a square-root like command that underlines the root. Using this,

```
\[
  \sqrt[-4]{\Sqrt[\Sqrt{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}]{\frac14}}
  =\sqrt[-4]{\Sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}^{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}}}]{4^{-1}}}
\]
```

now produces:

[image]

The root index is now underlined but the line is a little too thin! The only way around this that I can see is to use `\settowidth` from the [calc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/calc) package to calculate the width of the root and then draw a slightly thicker underline by hand using `\rlap`. The new underline requires a little bit of fine-tuning, so let's define a third variant of `\sqrt` that has an optional argument for the depth of the underline:

```
\newcommand\SQRT[3][-0.75mm]{%
  \settowidth\sqrtlength{$\scriptsize#2$}%
  \sqrt[\rlap{\rule[#1]\sqrtlength{0.6pt}}{#2}\hspace*{1mm}]{\cramped{#3}}%
}
```

With this in place, the code

```
\[
  \sqrt[-4]{\SQRT[-1.2mm]{\sqrt[-4]{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}}{\frac14}}
  =\sqrt[-4]{\SQRT{{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}^{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}}}}{4^{-1}}}
\]
```

produces:

[image]

This is reasonable, although I am sure that there are better ways to do this.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\newlength\sqrtlength

\begin{document}

  \[
    \sqrt[-4]{\sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}}]{\frac14}}
    =\sqrt[-4]{\sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}^{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}}}]{4^{-1}}}
  \]

  \newcommand\Sqrt[2][]{\sqrt[\underline{#1}\hspace*{1mm}]{\cramped{#2}}}

  \[
    \sqrt[-4]{\Sqrt[\Sqrt{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}]{\frac14}}
    =\sqrt[-4]{\Sqrt[{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}^{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}}}]{4^{-1}}}
  \]

  \newcommand\SQRT[3][-0.75mm]{%
    \settowidth\sqrtlength{$\scriptsize#2$}%
    \sqrt[\rlap{\rule[#1]\sqrtlength{0.6pt}}{#2}\hspace*{1mm}]{\cramped{#3}}%
  }

  \[
    \sqrt[-4]{\SQRT[-1.2mm]{\sqrt[-4]{(\frac14)^{\sqrt[-4]{\frac14}}}}{\frac14}}
    =\sqrt[-4]{\SQRT{{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}^{\sqrt[-4]{4^{-1}}}}}{4^{-1}}}
  \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great explanation. I was doing some testing by locking up the content of the `\sqrt` command option but as I had problems with the poorly constructed mathematical expression it didn't work.

Comment: @Aradnix Glad it was helpful:)